# how i pass parameter in sql reporting service in visual studio 2008 from front end through code?

Tags: asp.net

how i pass parameter in sql reporting service in visual studio 2008 from front end through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is using url access:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697.aspx